# How to evaluate $\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1-x}\:dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

How can I evaluate $\displaystyle \int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1-x}\:dx$ in an elegant (simple?) way? this integral seems very challenging, by simply expanding the binomial we have
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^3\left(1-x\right)}{1-x}\:dx-3\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1-x}\:dx$$
$$+3\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x\right)}{1-x}\:dx-\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^3\left(1+x\right)}{1-x}\:dx$$ which is clearly not helpful.

By using the sub $t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ I also obtain
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\ln ^3\left(t\right)}{t}\:dt-\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\ln ^3\left(t\right)}{1+t}\:dt$$ for that first integral $\displaystyle \ln ^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_n-2H_{2n}}{n}x^{2n}$ can be useful yet not so much for the $2$nd one.

The integral in question can also be converted into
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^3\left(\frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{1-x^2}\right)}{1-x}\:dx$$
$$=8\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^3\left(1-x\right)}{1-x}\:dx-12\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1-x^2\right)}{1-x}\:dx$$
$$+6\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln ^2\left(1-x^2\right)}{1-x}\:dx-\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^3\left(1-x^2\right)}{1-x}\:dx$$
The first and last integral can be done by using the beta function but the others are as challenging.

Comment: Here are somewhat similar integrals.I think that your integrals would also evaluate to big answer! https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Obrn.jpg, where **ES** is https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7akf.jpg

Comment: You should look as this document https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334598773

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2(x) \log ^3\left(\frac{1-x}{x+1}\right)}{1-x} \, dx=-8 \pi ^2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{21 \zeta (3)^2}{8}-\frac{21}{4} \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \log (2)-\frac{93}{4} \zeta (5) \log (2)+\frac{121 \pi ^6}{1440}-\frac{1}{3} \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)+\frac{1}{3} \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)$$